# rm -rf equivalent on Windows batch script

Tags: linux, windows, bash, shell

I want to delete multiple folders & files at once and the command should not broke even if some directories or files aren't preset. Also I use wildcards(`*`) to combine folder & file names.

I have the following command to delete folders in `Ubuntu`

```sh
rm -rf dist pkitree srktable cst_sign* cst_encrypt* *.log out
```

However when I try to do accompany the same in `Windows` `batch` like,

```
rd /s /q dist pkitree srktable cst_sign* cst_encrypt* *.log out 2> NUL
```

I still get error status and the wildcards are not recognised. Can someone help me achieving this behaviour in Windows as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try :

```
powershell -Command "Remove-Item -Recurse dist, *.log"
```